# tableView cell - select from another tableView

Tags: tableview

I am wondering if and how it could be possible to get the following working

From a `tableView cell` I want to get to another `tableView` with i.e. 10 different cells where the user has to choose on, and this one is set up in the previous table cell.
So let's say i.e 
The table cell is "choose" - touching this cell a `tableView` with 10 different cells opens up and the user can choose one of them. By choosing one of them it gets back to the inital `tableView` and the cell is filled with the users choice. How exactly to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can check with below code :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
if(tableView == displayTableView)
{
//Implementation for choiceTableview
choiceTableview.hidden = FALSE;
displayTableView.hidden = TRUE;
[choiceTableview reloadData];
}
else
{
//Implementation for displayTableView
choiceTableview.hidden = TRUE;
displayTableView.hidden = FALSE;
[displayTableView reloadData];
}
}
```

You have to check below condition in tableview method and display data according to ti:

```
if(tableView == displayTableView)
{
//Implementation for choiceTableview
}
else
{
//Implementation for displayTableView
}
```

This will help you to handle as many table view as you want. Cheers...